# A TCP connection between client and server, but no data transmission yet, and then client is down because of network issue, server can know that?

Tags: tcp

Client and server went through 3-way handshake to create a TCP connection, but they don't have any data communication, and then client disconnect because of network issue, **the server will know that situation ?**

**How to make server know that ?**

Comment: There is no reliable way to know that (see [two generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem)). In practice however the server can ping the client (and wait for pong with timeout) every now and then to approximate. Note that without any communication it simply is not possible at all.

Comment: Contrary to that, there is indeed a reliable way. Normally the server will expect a request from the client. The server should set a read timeout before trying to read the request. Then it can defend itself against slow clients, denial-of-service-clients, buggy clients, ...